# Is it possible to reuse definitions in Typhoon that have run-time arguments?

Tags: ios, typhoon

In our app, we are reusing a base view controller that provides common functionality to the views in our app. It needs to be injected with a view, and a view model. I've created a definition in our assembly similar to the following:

```
- (BaseViewController *)baseViewControllerWith:(UIView *)view andViewModel:(ViewModel *)viewModel {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MLBaseViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
    [definition useInitializer:@selector(initWithView:viewModel:) parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *initializer) {
        [initializer injectParameterWith:view];
        [initializer injectParameterWith:viewModel];
    }];
}];
```

The idea here is to reuse this definition for all the different uses. We might inject a SignUpView and SignUpViewModel:

```
- (SignUpViewController *)signUpViewControllerWithViewModel:(ViewModel *)viewModel {
  [self baseViewControllerWith:[self signUpView:viewModel] andViewModel:viewModel]
}
```

I got a rather hilarious runtime exception:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Congratulations you've tried to do something über-funky with Typhoon %). You are the 3rd person EVER to receive this error message. Returning a definition that is the result of a nested runtime argument is not supported. Instead unroll the definition.'
*`

The reason I'm doing it this way is because I have so many definitions that are using that baseViewController definition, I 'd like to be able to reuse it and just inject different views/viewmodels instead of having to rewrite that definition everywhere. Is this not supported in Typhoon?

Answer (score 1):

This has actually previously been requested [as an enhancement](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/issues/288) in Typhoon's issue tracker. If you like you could please comment and vote on this issue.